# No browser loading bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't seem to find a similar issue
On my website I am running into an issue where the browser progress bar will not show until the page is completely rendered.
This is particularly bad on a very slow page (which I am working on). It makes it look like the link may have been broken instead of just taking a little while.
Looking at the network
There is a GET method on the current page which returns a 304, this runs for about 3-5 seconds.
Once that finishes the new website will load with a near instant progress bar.
I am not sure what code I can share since this is happening everywhere on my site, it is just more noticeable on certain pages.
To see it at its worse go to http://www.swtorconquest.com/conquestweeks and click either "The Trade Emporium" or "Clash in Hyperspace".
I am having this issue both when testing locally and when the site is deployed.
I am using ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.5

Comment: So, you're asking us to debug your system without any source-code or configuration information? Since it's happen across your site, it could be well-buried, and without more information we can't really help you. Perhaps your question would do better on [sf] or [su].

Comment: Right now I don't know what I could post to actually help short of a link to my entire source code. I tried looking around (maybe I was phrasing it wrong) but I couldn't find anything about the browser loading bar not running. I know the page it is going to is beyond slow, but everything I can find while it is rendering the page there should be a bar.

Comment: Try taking out all of the <script>s, one by one, particularly any that are on that page alone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one thing, in `application.html.erb`, in `body` tag add this, it will solve your problem

```
<body data-no-turbolink>
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue exactly. Still a slow page but at least I now have a progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

The problem will almost certainly be **Turbolinks**, although this is just a guess. Lacking any other answers, I'll hopefully be able to give you some ideas:

---

When you load a page with `Turbolinks`, it will actually load the `<body>` tag of the page through Ajax, leading the `<head>` intact.

This causes a lot of problems if not handled correctly, one of which (we've found) being that your browser can no longer determine how quickly the page is loading. This is likely what your problem is.

---

Although I don't have an outright fix, I do have a test.

You can try removing any references to Turbolinks throughout the various pages in this part of your application. This can be done by using the following:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> => remove the turbolinks reference
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %> => remove the turbolinks reference
```

Also, you need to **remove Turbolinks from your Gemfile** & your `application.js`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require turbolinks => remove this line
```

This will give you the ability to gauge whether it's turbolinks which is preventing the status bar from loading correctly. If it is, then you'll have to work around this (I don't have any remedies off hand)

It must be noted that this test will not speed up the load time - it will merely show whether the status bar issue is caused by Turbolinks or not

Comment: Hey. Thanks! Another response gave me the way to fix the issue but I wanted to up vote you since you have a lot of information.